# store a matrix in Mongodb and query a single value using two keywords

Tags: mongodb, matrix, pymongo

I want to store the following matrix (shown in attachment) in MongoDB. I am using Python. I want to store the data as a matrix (or a more convenient alternative) and be able to query a single value using two keywords ("frequency" value and "input level" value). An example would be that if I query using the following two values e.g. 5.05e7 (frequency) and 6 (input level), I would get 1.94 in return.
How can I do this using Python (PyMongo)?
Thank you.

```
frequency= np.array([5.00E+07, 5.01E+7, 5.02E+07, 5.03E+07, 
5.04E+07, 5.05E+07, 5.06E+07, 5.07E+07, 5.08E+07, 5.09E+07, 
6.00E+07])
input_level= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
entry= np.matrix([
[8.53,  4.10,   5.79,   3.77,   8.95,   9.83, 6.15, 5.37,   2.61,   2.67,   8.01], 
[1.91,  7.63,   3.92,   7.45,   8.88,   6.18,   7.28, 9.33, 7.08,   8.78,   6.55],
[7.96,  8.10,   5.27,   2.58,   5.47,   2.63,   2.30, 6.24, 6.94,   5.68,   9.94],
[2.95,  2.52,   5.62,   3.54,   4.43,   9.17,   9.56, 6.66, 5.25,   8.57,   7.52],
[5.48,  2.03,   8.26,   4.16,   1.55,   6.77,   1.96, 3.73, 6.26,   9.77,   8.67],
[4.99,  9.45,   8.97,   9.87,   3.11,   1.94,   5.20, 1.47, 1.94,   8.08,   5.08],
[9.49,  4.28,   6.82,   2.72,   7.94,   8.90,   4.97, 8.61, 1.37,   5.91,   7.41],
[2.32,  4.75,   3.72,   3.03,   4.58,   3.87,   8.89, 3.14, 6.31,   5.78,   3.50],
[1.82,  2.47,   7.78,   1.67,   4.19,   8.68,   7.10, 1.89, 3.51,   2.13,   7.77],
[8.52,  6.06,   1.38,   2.96,   9.38,   8.43,   4.00, 2.55, 6.83,   3.57,   2.90]])
```

[image]

Comment: Showing some code would be helpful.  For example, how is this stored in Python? ... a Pandas DataFrame? ... a NumPy array? ...?

Comment: Do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GyPt-ObaqgJ)?

Comment: i am looking to avoid the manual work of inserting the data. is there any other way than the process you have shown?

Comment: I didn't manually type it.  It's just a bit more Python from what you've shown to create a Python array of dictionaries (dicts).  You can use `pymongo` to insert the entire array as your collection in one command.

Comment: can you please share that code? 
for i in range(len(frequency)):
    info= {'_id':'combo', 'frequency':frequency[0], 'input level': input_level[i], 'gain value': entry[0, i]}  
    raw.insert_one(info)
i am using this code and getting the following error:
cannot encode object: 1, of type:

Comment: Create an empty array, like `mongodb_collection = []` and then use a nested `for` loop to populate the array with dicts.  Something like (you''ll need to properly indent this, etc.) ... `for f_idx, f in enumerate(frequency):  for p_idx, p in enumerate(input_level): 
 mongodb_collection.append({"frequency": f, "input_level": p, "value": entry.item(p_idx, f_idx)})`.  I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to do this, but with such a small amount of data, I don't see how it matters.